# Javascript regex shorthand?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to enjoy some of the awesome javascript code golf submissions on anarchy code golf, but I keep seeing things like:

```
for(;s=readline();)print("h"+/t.*/(s))
```

...which was the JS winner for: http://golf.shinh.org/p.rb?ttp

I don't understand how that is correct javascript syntax, and I even tried resubmitting that, but it said object is not a function, which is something along the lines of what I would expect to happen.

Was this some kind of glitch or shorthand or something in an older javascript version?

Comment: It looks like `/t.*/` creates a regex object and applies it to the string in `s`, and then appends "h" to the front. I wouldn't know whether `/t.*/(s)` syntax is valid though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Was this some kind of glitch or shorthand or something in an older javascript version?

More or less, yes. According to [that site's version info](http://golf.shinh.org/version.rb), it uses SpiderMonkey (Mozilla's JavaScript engine), which used to have the feature that regular-expression objects were callable; that is, that if `re` was a regular-expression object, then `re(...)` was equivalent to `re.exec(...)`. That feature was removed in [this change](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/001bfbd35ed9), a result of [Bug 582717](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=582717), and that site has since updated to a version that incorporates that removal.

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was hoping for.